# curl и перемещение по сайту

Tags: php, curl

Столкнулся с проблемой: нужно посредством curl перемещаться после авторизации на сайте по внутренним страницам админки, авторизуюсь - записываю куки, дальше кидает на главную админки, после чего не могу достучаться до других страниц, пишет `Error in exception handler.`, не могу понять в чем проблема, вот код:

```
//получаю токен
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.ru/auth/login');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $pageLogin = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $token = (new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($pageLogin)))->query("//input[@name='_token']")->item(0)->getAttribute("value");


        $postFields['_token'] = $token;
        $postFields['email'] = $email;
        $postFields['password'] = $password;

        $post = '';

        foreach ($postFields as $key => $value) {
            $post .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
        }

        $post = substr($post, 0, -1);

        //авторизируюсь с токеном
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.ru/auth/login');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $page = curl_exec($ch); // make request
        curl_close($ch);

        $postFields = array(
            '_token' => $token,
            'type' => $data['user_type'],
        );
        foreach ($postFields as $key => $value) {
            $post .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
        }

        $post = substr($post, 0, -1);
        //отправляю другой пост на другую страницу
        $ch = curl_init();
        $url2 = 'https://www.example.ru/post/create';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $page = curl_exec($ch); // make request
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: скорее всего ошибка на стороне сервера (сайта)

Comment: @Naumov через браузер работает нормально, а через curl - ошибка, есть идеи что может вызывать такую ошибку?

Comment: Либо полностью воспроизводить браузер, то есть user agent, cookie, заголовки и т.д.

Comment: Либо смотреть логи на сервере сайта, что там происходит

Comment: Либо работа на сайте осуществляется через javascript

Comment: @DmitryKozlov это точно нет, пробовал без js через браузер смотреть

Comment: @Naumov проблема как раз в том, что доступа к серверу у меня нет и нужно автоматизировать действия посредством curl, по поводу имитации браузера, интересная идея, насколько я понимаю для этого мне нужно просто получать и передавать заголовки каждый раз, помимо того что у меня уже указано в setopt?